# How to reduce apk size when using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, apk, android-ffmpeg

App is developed it's size is hardly 30MB and when integrated FFmpeg Library its size goes to 135MB which is Too much.

Anyone know anything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: facing same issue my app size is 225 mb, I only added ffmpeg-kit-flutter

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible do very much improvements.

FFMPEG is made by binary and libraries that are necessarie to let it work.

You can:

- use a Mobile version of FFMPEG, but it could lack some codes for obliviously reasons: https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit
- create a separated APK each for one CPU Architecture: ARM7, ARM8, X86, X64, etc... In this way only 25-30Mb are included in final APK

Answer (score 0):

use

```
implementation "com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-min:4.4.LTS"
```

according of this [link](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg)